# replace nan values with the mean of other rows

Tags: matlab, nan, mean

Consider the following example:

```
Jday = datenum('2007-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1:...
    datenum('2009-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Jday2 = datenum('2008-01-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):1:...
    datenum('2010-12-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');

Data{1} = [Jday;1+(length(Jday)-1).*rand(1,length(Jday))]';
Data{2} = [Jday2;1+(length(Jday)-1).*rand(1,length(Jday))]';
Data{3} = [Jday;1+(length(Jday)-1).*rand(1,length(Jday))]';

for i = 1:length(Data);
    d_nan{i} = floor(1+(length(Jday)-1).*rand(1,100));
end

for i = 1:length(Data);
    a(i) = length(d_nan{i});
    for ii = 1:a(i);
        Data{i}(d_nan{i}(ii),2) = nan;
    end
end
```

In this example I have a cell array 'Data' which contains three cell arrays, the first column of each cell array contains the Julian date of the value in the second column. There are numerous nan values in each cell array. I would like to replace the nan values in each cell array with the average of the values in the other cells for that specific julian date. My problem is complicated due to the three cells not showing data at the same times (although Data{1} and Data{3} have the same days.) If the julian date were identical between the three cells this problem could be solved by using isnan to find the location of the nans and then replace those rows by the nanmean of the other rows (in the other cells).

Could anyone suggest an effective way of tackling this problem? Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you guarantee that all cell arrays are of the same dimension? If yes, then why aren't you using an N-by-6 matrix to store everything?

Comment: Nope, I cant guarantee they will be the same dimensions. Each cell represent a different location and this will change.

Comment: So what happens if there's a `NaN` value without a matching date in the other arrays?

Comment: In that case, it would just stay as nan.

Comment: Did you check my solution?

Comment: yes, great, took some time to follow but I understand it now. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be:

1. Concatenating all data and locating the `NaN` values:

   ```
   D = [vertcat(Data{:})];
   nanidx = find(isnan(D(:, 2)));
   ```
2. For each index `k` of such `NaN` value in the concatenated matrix `D`, finding other entries with the same date:

   ```
   entries = find(D(:, 1) == D(k, 1));
   ```
3. Filter the non-`NaN` values from those entries and replace the original `NaN` at position `k` with the mean value:

   ```
   values = D(~isnan(D(entries, 2)) & ~ismember(entries, nanidx), 2);
   D(k, 2) = mean(values);
   ```
4. Converting everything back into a cell array:

   ```
   Data = mat2cell(D, cellfun('length', Data), 2)';
   ```

Here's the final, copy-paste friendly code:

```
D = [vertcat(Data{:})];
nanidx = find(isnan(D(:, 2)));
for k = transpose(nanidx(:))
    entries = find(D(:, 1) == D(k, 1));
    values = D(~isnan(D(entries, 2)) & ~ismember(entries, nanidx), 2);
    D(k, 2) = mean(values);
end
Data = mat2cell(D, cellfun('length', Data), 2)';
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem, although it's not exactly what you asked for. At each NaN value, it replaces it with the mean of the values interpolated at that day with NaNs removed from the interpolation.

```
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:length(Jday)
        if isnan(Data{i}(j,2))
            d = Data{i}(j,1);
            Data{i}(j,2) = mean([ ...
                interp1(Data{1}(find(~isnan(Data{1}(:,2))),1),Data{1}(find(~isnan(Data{1}(:,2))),2),d) ...
                interp1(Data{2}(find(~isnan(Data{2}(:,2))),1),Data{2}(find(~isnan(Data{2}(:,2))),2),d) ...
                interp1(Data{3}(find(~isnan(Data{3}(:,2))),1),Data{3}(find(~isnan(Data{3}(:,2))),2),d)]);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: interpolating wont really work for my data, but thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I didn't realize you were alright with leaving NaNs. Added a solution to do what you originally asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you saw the edit (I'm a new user, so still learning how this works), so here is a solution that does what you ask and leaves NaNs where the other two don't have the same date.

```
for i = 1:3
    for j = 1:length(Jday)
        if isnan(Data{i}(j,2))
            d = Data{i}(j,1);
            if (~isempty(find(Data{:,1}==d,1)) && ...
                ~isempty(find(Data{:,2}==d,1)) && ...
                ~isempty(find(Data{:,3}==d,1)))
                Data{i}(j,2) = nanmean([ ...
                    Data{1}(find(Data{:,1}==d,1),2) ...
                    Data{2}(find(Data{:,2}==d,1),2) ...
                    Data{3}(find(Data{:,3}==d,1),2) ]);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You should rather use the edit link to improve your previous answer rather than posting this as a separate answer.